# Как проверить, является ли заданное число степенью двойки?

Tags: c#

Как проверить, является ли заданное число степенью двойки.

Например:

256 = 2^8

8 = 2^3

Как можно это осуществить в C#?

Comment: Степень двойки делается простым регистровым сдвигом `2 << 7 == 128 << 1 == 256`. Ну а дальше можно например в цикле перебирать остатком по делению. Либо, как уже наверное догадались, посчитать в числе кол-во бит равных 1.

Comment: Ага, либо воспользоваться школьными знаниями о логарифмах: взять логарифм по основанию два.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/600293/5752652

Comment: Для целых, как и в любом С-подобном языке -- `if ((x & (x - 1)) == 0) { // это степень двойки }`

Comment: Хороший простой вопрос. Не вижу смысла минусовать или ставить флаг за закрытие ¯\_(ヅ)_/¯

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/600293/12888024

Comment: Если удалось разобраться, отметьте галочкой наиболее полезный ответ. Так же зайдите к себе в профиль и проделайте эту де самую операцию в ваших прошлых вопросах.

Answer (score 5):

Ещё один [классический способ](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2):

```
n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0
```

---

Там по ссылке ещё много всяких битовых трюков.

---

Как это трюк работает? А вот как. Запишем число `n` в двоичной системе, и рассмотрим самую правую единицу в двоичном представлении числа `n`. У числа `n - 1` будет на месте этой единицы ноль, а справа от него единицы:

```
n      : xxxxxx1000
1      : 0000000001
n - 1  : xxxxxx0111
```

а остальные двоичные цифры (обозначенные как `x`) не поменяются. Поэтому после операции `&` получится вот что:

```
n&(n-1): xxxxxx0000
```

Это число будет равно нулю тогда и только когда, когда все `xxxxxx` равны нулю. Единственный случай, где наше соображение не проходит — число 0: там нету «самой правой» единицы вовсе, так что это случай приходится рассматривать отдельно.

---

Интересно, что gcc и clang выдают на этот код и код из ответа @aepot строго одинаковый ассемблерный код: https://godbolt.org/z/xWx1qT

Comment: ну так, оптимизации в плюсах работают, можно еще JIT ассемблер глянуть.

Comment: @aepot: [вот](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2AqAphMOgN7rZXYBGA9nQDbYCSEACnQO6EBOA8gDN8XOgH0AbmF5IAFAEsAdsGyKArlBp8AlNgC8APlUatvbEYAM2AGTXss9Zr43sAWkendevcae8A3JTU9EysHNx8QiLiUrwICsq+nvpGHs6WNnYOJs5ZaWau2EjaXj4WgWgAvkA===)

Answer (score 3):

Есть простой арифметический способ.

```cs
private bool IsPowerOfTwo(int number)
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= number; x *= 2)
    {
        if (x == number) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine(IsPowerOfTwo(256));
```

Но все же к вопросам про двойки всегда приходит лучшим ответом (как правило) двоичная арифметика и немного знаний о том, как числа хранятся в памяти в двоичном виде.

```cs
private bool IsPowerOfTwo(int number)
{
    return number > 0 && (number & -number) == number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var num = 16;

var log = Math.Log2(num);

if (log - Math.Truncate(log) != 0)
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{num} is not a power of 2.");
```

Но тут кроется куча проблем.

Comment: `Но тут кроется куча проблем` так расскажите о них, или покажите надежное решение.

Comment: я льшь предположил, что 0.000000000000000000000000001 погрешность в вычислении  `Math.Log2()` может привести к краху данной концепции. Но прока я проверил на числах от 0 до ~65000 и всё отработало нормально. Если `num` будет не целочисленным значением, а `float/double`  к примеру.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]